# SetState doesn't rerender component after calling it in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to change a route in my component if the user has logged in before and that information is saved. I see `setState` being called in the `componentDidMount` method, but the `render` method is not being called again, not "logging" in the user.

If I log in the user, `loggedIn()` gets called and the component is rerendered with the correct state set.

According to the ReactJS docs, I can call `setState` in `componentDidMount` right away but it doesn't seem to render using the correct state. Any help would be appreciated

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect, withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from '../components/signIn/signInComponent';
import Register from '../components/register/registerComponent';
import Dashboard from '../components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

interface AuthState {
  isAuthenticated: boolean
}

class Routes extends React.Component<any, AuthState>{

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({
      isAuthenticated: true
    });
  }

  loggedIn = () => {
    this.setState({
      isAuthenticated: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <Route path='/' exact render={() => (
              !this.state.isAuthenticated ? (<Redirect to='/signin'/>) : (<Dashboard/>)
            )}/>
            <Route path='/signin' exact render={() => (
              <SignIn onLoggedIn={this.loggedIn}/>
            )}/>
            <Route path='/register' exact component={Register}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Routes);
```

Comment: Careful, setState does not execute/complete “right away” there will be a moment where isAuthenticated will be false causing your routing to navigate to login view. Do you have a redirect in that login view?

Comment: I don't have a redirect on the login view, but I'm not getting a rerender at all. If there is a delay in the change, I'm fine with that, but it doesn't trigger the `render` call at all

Comment: Are you sure a rerender isn’t happening? If isAuthenticated is false it will go to /signin/ view. Once it’s there, you’re first Route with ternary operation checking isAuthenticated to route to dashboard will not hit because the url is no longer /. So unless you have redirect logic in signin view to redirect to dashboard, it will never get there unless you are redirecting back to / after some event so that first route logic attempts execute again after isAuthenticated as been set to true.

Comment: The router documentation has a great example for an auth flow https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow it uses the values of the redirect to navigate the user to originally requested route after a login, definitely check it out.